# Show notification after chrome extension is installed

Tags: ajax, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Like many Chrome extensions do, when users install my Chrome extension, I want to tell them to "Click on this icon to start using the extension". As shown below:

[image]

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question, that notification appears automatically after installing the `.crx` file, no need to write a separate script.